# RoboAsyncTask deprecated, what is the new solution

Tags: android, roboguice

Hi iv taken over a project which uses RoboAsyncTask in their project. But they also relied on RoboGuice 1. Now that RoboGuice 3.0 has come im looking to upgrade, but its not very happy with my currente roboasynctask usage.

Iv read that I should use AndroidCallable? Is this right?
Is there somewhere i can read how to use it properly?
The wiki: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki still talks about RoboAsyncTask and nothing else.

So I just wonder what the new proper way of using this functionallity is.